# Is not it better to use adopt rather then use revert to

Tags: gre

Recently, I have faced a question like below:
The new systematic nomenclature was so (i)**__ that many chemists preferred to (ii)__** the older trivial names that were at least shorter. At least, that is the ostensible reason. Actually, tradition seems to carry more weight than (iii)____ with some scientists.

Blank (i)
A. succinct 
B. cumbersome 
C. irrational

Blank (ii)
D. revert to 
E. adopt 
F. suspend

Blank (iii)
G. chronology 
H. longevity 
I. system

And I answered it:
BEI
whenever the answer given is:
BDI.

My question is if it is not much suitable to use adopt the system rather than going back to the system?

Comment: If the chemists referred to switched to IUPAC then back again, they obviously reverted to the older nomenclature. If they never actually adopted IUPAC recommendations, you need F' = 'retain'.

Answer (score 1):

"Adopt" should be used when starting something new, whereas "revert" should be using when returning to a previous behavior.

Looking at the [Merriam-Webster definition of adopt](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/adopt), it says "to begin to use", whereas the definition of [revert](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/revert) is "to go back to" or "to return to".

If we substitute the words "begin to use" and "return to using", it is clear that "revert" is correct:

> The new systematic nomenclature was so *cumbersome* that many
>   chemists preferred to **begin to use** the older trivial names that
>   were at least shorter.

vs

> The new systematic nomenclature was so *cumbersome* that many
>   chemists preferred to **return to using** the older trivial names that
>   were at least shorter.

Comment: Can't put it any better than this :)

Comment: This goes beyond the original three, but would "sustain" belong in this list, so we have "the new way", "the old way", "the current way"?